# Getting response code 404 on upload image on server in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to upload an image to a server. I used the code from SO question: [Blackberry jde : how to upload an image in server using MultipartPostData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342577/blackberry-jde-how-to-upload-an-image-in-server-using-multipartpostdata)

But the image is not uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% certain that the URL you are POSTing to is valid?

HTTP 404 is "resource not found"; for a POST that would typically mean the CGI program, script or controller is not at the path you've given.

Comment: Can you please give some suggestion so that I can wonk perfectly. As I am facing problem. Please help!!!!

Comment: You have code that calls a web URL, to send the data. What URL is that?